# Set up log rotate in Mac

Tags: python, apache-kafka, logrotate

I have kafka consumer and output which is live stream of data should be captured on hourly basis in a log file.
Took help from this link
[1]: https://richard-purves.com/2017/11/08/log-rotation-mac-admin-cheats-guide/

Created a log file kafka.log in /var/log and config file for the same named kafka.conf  in /etc/newsyslog.conf

Tried running kafka consumer that creates log file under /var/log/kafka.log

python3 consumer.py --kafka-broker "xxx" --kafka-topic "yyy" --kafka-group-id cxel-yellow-vsg-qoe --kafka-ssl-keyfile  "key"  --kafka-ssl-certfile  "certificate  --kafka-ssl-cafile  /usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem  --schemas prod --kafka-security-protocol SSL **>>  sudo /var/log/kafka.log 2>&1 &**

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [apple.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Answer (score 0):

> kafka consumer [whose] output [is a] live stream of data [and] should be captured on hourly basis in a log file.

This is precisely the use case for **Kafka Connect**, not some standard Python consumer

Kafka comes with `connect-standalone.sh` to get you started

You may use the HDFS2 Sink Connector provided by Confluent to write data into (approximate} hourly files (one file per topic partition) using its `HourlyPartitioner` class, bounded also by a consumer fetch size

You don't need to install HDFS or download Hadoop to use it. In the configuration for a file location, you can provide `file:///tmp/kafka-logs`, for example